# C# .Net - How to make application wait until all threads created in Library are finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, frameworks, shared-libraries, application-shutdown

I am trying to create a logging library and things are good until the application shutdown is called. When application shutdown is called, any unfinished thread is killed and the specific log is lost.

As of now application exits even before the first 10 threads are complete. I want help on how to make the application wait until all threads created by library are done.

NOTE: 
Requirement I got are like this. Modifications should be only in the class 'Logging' since this will be a library and will be provided to end users. Handling of logging issues during app shutdown must be done within it. This is where I have trouble now.

Alternatively a solution like create an event in logging class to trigger all logging complete, and ask user to call app exit on that event is possible, but that I am trying to avoid since it adds that burden to end user and adds complexity for implementations. There is a possibility they may skip it, which I do not want. I am looking for a solution like user should do 'Logging.AddException(....)' and then forget about it.

Please help. Provide comments if you are not clear about the idea.

Here is the full code abstract which you can put into a console application.
**Note: Look for comments in CASE 1 and CASE 2.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultithreadKeepAlive
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LogLoadTest();
        Logging.AddExceptionEntryAsync(new Exception("Last Exception"));

        /*
         * USE CASE 1: Enable the below lines and you will see how long it is supposed to take.
         * Notice that currentDomain_ProcessExit will not trigger if below gets uncommented
         */
        //Console.WriteLine("Main thread wait override");
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void LogLoadTest()
    {
        //In real world this will be called from any place of application like startup or just after application shutdown is initiated.
        //: NOTICE: Unlike the sample here, this will never be on loop and I am not looking for handling multithreads in this class.
        //      That responsibility I am planning to assign to Logging class.
        // AND ALSO the class Logging is going to be in a seperate signed assembly where user of this class ('Program') should not worry about multithreads.
        Task t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
           t =  Logging.AddExceptionEntryAsync(new Exception("Hello Exception " + i), "Header info" + i);
        }
    }
}

public class Logging
{
    static List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    static AppDomain currentDomain;
    static Logging()
    {
        currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.ProcessExit += currentDomain_ProcessExit;
    }

    public static async Task AddExceptionEntryAsync(Exception ex, string header = "")
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddExceptionEntry(ex, header));
        tasks.Add(t);
        await t;
    }

    public static void AddExceptionEntry(Exception ex, string header)
    {
        /* Exception processing and write to file or DB. This might endup in file locks or 
         * network or any other cases where it will take delays from 1 sec to 5 minutes. */
        Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1, 1000));
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    static void currentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Application shutdown triggerd just now.");
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();    //1st attempt.
            //Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); //2nd attempt
            while (tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) //3rd attempt.
            {
            }
            /* USE CASE 2: IF WORKING GOOD, THIS WILL BE DISPLAYED IN CONSOLE AS LAST 
             * MESSAGE OF APPLICATION AND WILL WAIT FOR USER. THIS IS NOT WORKING NOW.*/
            Console.WriteLine("All complete"); //this message should show up if this work properly
            Console.ReadLine(); //for testing purpose wait for input from user after every thread is complete. Check all 40 threads are in console.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tried it with the thread function join()? If exiting you could call the method for each running thread. So the program waits until they are finished.

Comment: Why is this function: `AddExceptionEntryAsync(Exception ex, string header)` not marked `async` and just use a `Task.Delay` inside of it? Have you read the documentation on [`Process.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit(v=vs.110).aspx)? Specifically this part *"The total execution time of all ProcessExit event handlers is limited, just as **the total execution time of all finalizers is limited at process shutdown. The default is two seconds**. An unmanaged host can change this execution time by calling the method with the enumeration value."*

Comment: Ron Beyer, lorenz albert:  Tried them all.  They work on normal scenarios where application runs as normal. Here when application shutdown nothing stops it from killing all the threads. What ever I tried threads gets killed and application exists without writing logs.

Comment: Yes, for the reason I highlighted, this is not going to change by Waiting for the tasks to complete. The only way to extend shutdown time is to use an unmanaged host to increase the execution time, otherwise you should be handling this **before** the user decides to exit the application. Depending  on what UI framework you are using, there may be an event to intercept, but not in a Console app, the application stops when `main` stops, at that point the app has 2 seconds to clean up or the runtime will step in and do it for you.

Comment: By the way, I think you should do some more reading on the `async`/`await` pattern, you have some methods marked `async` but they return `void` instead of `Task` ([Avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)). You are also calling an `async` method synchronously and then generating tasks manually. There are a lot of red flags in the implementation here and I think a lot of core issues will clear up when those get fixed.

Comment: hmm .. Ron Beyer .. yes what you explained must be the root cause! I am trying to find a work around for it. Create an unmanaged app is the responsibility of implementer since this might go into a WCF serivce, console or in a windows and WPF application. As of now I am keeping event option as the last resort for this.

Comment: yup.. that 'async' thingy; was a mess.. I played with this a lot. corrected it now!! Thanks Ron  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now I myself found a workaround.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the current thread Wait until any of the pending messages/Exceptions/Logs are completly written into respective sources.
    /// Call this method before application is shutdown to make sure all logs are saved properly.
    /// </summary>
    public static void WaitForLogComplete()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.Values.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

This waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

**UPDATE** : using async/await

With async and await, we formalize and clarify how asynchronous, non-blocking methods begin and end. An async method can return only void or a Task.

```
static void Main()
{
// Create task and start it.
// ... Wait for it to complete.
Task task = new Task(AsyncMethod);
task.Start();
task.Wait();
}

public static async void AsyncMethod(){
await AnotherMehod();}

static async Task AnotherMehod() { //TODO}
```

Comment: Rejeb: This is useful if application is running as normal. My problem is that it will get killed when application is exits. I want to keep the application alive adn threads running until all threads are done.

Comment: @digitally_inspired i've updated my answer with async/await

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Consider changing to Task.Run() if you do not want the scheduler to be involved. I'm also assuming you want to wait until all async tasks finish.

```
public static AddExceptionEntry(Exception ex, string header = "")
{
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddExceptionEntry(ex, header));
    tasks.Add(t);

    WaitForExecutionAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
}

public static async Task WaitForExecutionAsync()
{
    if(tasks.Count >0) 
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    // Raise Event.
}
```

To Block just call this to run sync vs async:

```
WaitForExecution().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Step1 I am assuming this is the change.
Task t = Task.Run(() => AddExceptionEntryAsync(ex, header));
//Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddExceptionEntryAsync(ex, header));
tasks.Add(t);

Next one WaitForExecution().. where do you think this need to be called?

Comment: Is AddExceptionEntry going to get called my multiple threads and that's the reason to keep a task list and wait for execution?

Comment: yes it will be called from any part of application at any time. and in the vent of application shutdown it should be able to finish the job without getting killed!!

Comment: Because you are using a List instead of a concurrent collection a race condition will arise should the tasks.Add portion of your code be called at the same time. Also without knowing what exactly you are trying to accomplish its difficult to know the best solution. The AppDomain class has some other events you should consider like UnhandledException and DomainUnload.

Comment: Nice finding.. Thanks. Yes The main thing I am trying to find is about stopping application from shutting down until the operations are complete. I am doing it in explicit way where user need to take care of calling the method which uses Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); . I want to remove this responsibility from user or to make sure user will call it before application initiates shutdown. I am kind of stuck here!

Comment: If the logging class was not static, then you could wrap the Logging class variable and make your call when the shutdown is triggered. Really you need to block while shutting down. Look over CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken as well, You could use it to signal shutdown to the Logging class.

Comment: Sounds like you need to block your logging operation on shutdown. Create an object field in your logging class called object _syncObject = new object();